# printf double with up to n decimals but not more as needed

Tags: c++, c, printf

I want to trail the output of a double to 2 decimals or less. Consider following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "%.2f\n", 2.    );
    printf( "%.2f\n", 2.5   );
    printf( "%.2f\n", 2.25  );
    printf( "%.2f\n", 2.125 );
}
```

The output is

```
2.00
2.50
2.25
2.12
```

Is there any way to print the values with less than 2 decimals, in case less are needed? I mean the desired output is

```
2
2.5
2.25
2.12
```

Answers with iomanip are allowed. I'm focusing on C++, not C but the example is c-only.

I know, that it is often not possible because double values are not precise, but in my examples they are because all fractional parts are powers of 2

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48d35e381250928b)

Comment: Why would this even be needed?

Comment: You can have separate setprecision's if you know the outputs? But if you are trying to check if the next value is 0 then exclude it then it is not possible.

Comment: The example is constructed to be minimal. Please assume, that value is unknown but I don't want to print useless zeros at the end

Comment: Not fantastic but sprintf result in a string and then right trim it, manually...

Comment: @OmidCompSCI that's what one often expected. Pocket calculators never output trailing zeros

Answer (score 2):

If the absolute value is known to be between `0.006` and `999.995`, you could use format `%.3g`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "%.3g\n", 2.    );
    printf( "%.3g\n", 2.5   );
    printf( "%.3g\n", 2.25  );
    printf( "%.3g\n", 2.125 );
}
```

Output is

```
2
2.5
2.25
2.12
```

But for the general case, trimming the string converted by `snprintf()` seems required:

```
void print_double_with_at_most_2_decimal_figures(double x) {
    char buf[400];
    int i = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2f", x);
    while (i > 0 && buf[i - 1] == '0')
        buf[--i] = '\0';
    if (i > 0 && buf[i - 1] == '.')
        buf[--i] = '\0';
    fputs(buf, stdout);
}
```

Comment: I usually use your 'general' case as well – not with such a counterintuitive function name, though :P

Comment: @RadLexus: of course! I made the name a bit more specific ;-)

Answer (score -3):

One way to do it is to take the value that is `2.00` and then assign it to a variable. This should take care of the extra 0's and give you the correct answer.

Comment: No it won't!!!!